# Clean up diep.io sandbox?

Tags: diep.io

Is it possible to remove every square, triangle and pentagon from sandbox mode in diep.io? 
I tried with some tanks but it didn't work. They are always respawning. Does anyone know the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a way to clear the sandbox:

1. Become necromancer
2. Destroy every pentagon and triangle until they become squares
3. Collect every square with necromancer.

There will be no objects left, only the necromancer drones..
When collecting a square with necromancer it does not respawn.

Answer (score 2):

This will never happen.

Every time you attack a shape, a new one spawn instantly.  This does two things.  It will reduce the need for a randomized loop that spawns the shape, and it maintains the original amount of shapes on the field at all times.